# Interaction energy in an electromagnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, potential, hamiltonian-formalism

I'm reading [notes on QED](https://www.lkv.uni-rostock.de/storages/uni-rostock/Alle_MNF/Physik_Qms/Lehre_Scheel/quantenoptik/Quantenoptik-Vorlesung8.pdf) and they are deriving the Hamiltonian of an electric field. They find the interaction energy for particles with mass $m_a$, charge $q_a$, momentum $\mathbf{p}_a$ at position $\mathbf{r}_a$, in an electric field $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r},t)$ as

$$H_{int} = \sum_a \frac{q_a}{m_a}\mathbf{p}_a(t)\cdot \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}_a,t) + \frac{q_a^2}{2m_a}\mathbf{A}^2(\mathbf{r}_a,t).\tag{14.16}$$

How is this derived/justified?

Comment: Related (and I think the question statement there answers your question):  [About Hamiltonian equation for a charged particle in a magnetic field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/319385/about-hamiltonian-equation-for-a-charged-particle-in-a-magnetic-field/345682)

Comment: As far as where the Lagrangian comes from, most upper-level undergrad classical mechanics texts will discuss that.  I like Taylor's *Classical Mechanics*, personally.

Comment: Beware of this interaction Hamiltonian, it only makes sense as approximate description of EM interaction of particles with external field, neglecting mutual interaction of the particles. This is because  $\mathbf A$ there is the external field ("free field"), which is finite at the position of the particle. This approach does not take into account the fact that particles mutual interaction is more complicated than the Coulomb term can describe; there is magnetic interaction, retardation, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One starts off with the Hamiltonian for a point particle in the electromagnetic field:

$$H = \frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m} + q V$$

knowing that $\mathbf{p}$ is actually the canonical momentum $\mathbf{p}_{can} = \mathbf{p} + q \mathbf{A}$. Plugging it in the Hamiltonian for many particles indexed by $a$ one gets:

$$H = \sum_a \frac{1}{2m_a}\left( \mathbf{p}_{a} - q_a \mathbf{A_a}\right)^2 +\sum_a q_aV_a$$

Expanding the first terms provides the answer:

$$H =  \sum_a\frac{\mathbf{p}^2_a}{2m_a} +  \sum_a q_a\frac{\mathbf{p}_a \mathbf{A}_a}{m_a} +  \sum_a q_a^2\frac{\mathbf{A}^2_a}{2m_a}      + \sum_a q_a V_a$$